# word vba, how to get rid of "Spurious" controls on userform

Tags: vba, ms-word, controls, userform

Just for the "fun" of it, I wrote a routine to list all the controls on a userform:

```
 Call ListAllControlsOn(myNiceForm)

 Sub ListAllControlsOn(aUserForm As UserForm)
   Dim ctrl As Control
   i = 1
   For Each ctrl In aUserForm.Controls
       Debug.Print "  Control #" & i & " of type " & TypeName(ctrl) & " is named " & ctrl.Name; ""
       If ctrl.Name = "Frame36" Then ctrl.Delete ' Delete method is not valid :-(
       i = i + 1
   Next ctrl
  End Sub
```

It works as expected, but it also prints the names of some controls I didn't know I have, and which I don't want.

```
 Control #14 of type Frame is named Frame35
 Control #15 of type Frame is named Frame36
 Control #16 of type Frame is named Frame37
```

Those extra Frames are not hurting me, but I want to know how to find and/or get those boogers off the userform.

Comment: ???? .... you have already found them .... `ctrl.delete`  .... what are you really asking?

Comment: jsotola, when I said "find", I really meant to find the Frames with my *eyes* on the graphical userform. Any idea why I can't see them? I will try the .delete method, which I thought had given me some kind of syntax error or runtime error.

Comment: you should have said `how to make them visible`  .... maybe they are outside of the form area.  ...  use the `properties` window to check the control's location and to move it if necessary

Comment: the frames may be there to place radio buttons into logical groups

Answer (score 0):

```
ctrl.delete
```

I found a ton of examples of how to loop through controls and delete certain ones, with a simple [Google Search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=excel%20vba%20loop%20through%20controls%20delete).

Use an `If` statement to `ctrl.delete` when `TypeName(ctrl)="Frame"`

More info about `If` statements [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=excel%20vba%20if%20statement).

Comment: The tons of examples you found were not Word VBA examples, I suppose. I added the following line inside my For loop, and I got "Runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method."

     If ctrl.Name = "Frame36" Then ctrl.Delete

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question is asked more out of curiosity than need... you can, after all, `TAB` through all the controls...

I think the basic problem is that (using VBA at least) you can only programmatically `.Remove` 'Controls' that were added programmatically at Runtime... [see here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/430188-programmatically-remove-control-userform-post3671713.html#post3671713)

There are, however, some plugins for the VBA IDE that might help - e.g. MZ-Tools helps explore userforms, and (I have just confirmed) it can delete controls from userforms.

[image: MZ-Tools Control Explorer]

Comment: The best comment so far is that it's not possible to delete controls that were not added programmatically. That doesn't really explain why the bogus controls can't be seen even if I try to change their .Top and .Left properties to a visible location on the userform.  But curiously, my For loop stopped listing the bogus Frames after I modified the tab order of other controls. Weird. Probably a bug. I will drop this issue and move on. Thanks to all contributors.

Comment: Welcome to MS Weird 